# R: linear mixed effects plus MCMC estimation

Tags: r, linear-model, markov-chain-montecarlo

In a paper I wrote a few years ago, I wrote the following:

> All results were analyzed using linear mixed models effects, with Subjects and Items as random effects. I present p-values estimated from MCMC sampling. All the calculations have been done with the aid of the R statistical software, and specifically, the packages lm4e (Bates et al 2009) and languageR (Baayen 2009)

One of my undergraduates has read this paper and has asked me for the specific R code I used to generate these p-values. Regrettably, I can't find the specific code in my notes anymore, and all my attempts at reproducing it have failed (including my attempts to find the tutorial pdf that I used to originally learn this particular way of doing things. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: My guess is that you were using the `mcmcsamp()` function, which has been deprecated since lme4 v1.0-0 (search the [News](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html) on CRAN and see `?mcmcsamp` for the rationale and alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a challenging question to answer, but I think the current version of `lme4` doesn't have MCMC anymore. A quick google search gave [this](https://seriousstats.wordpress.com/tag/mcmc-methods/) blog post which seems relevant and contains some code which is likely similar to what you used.

I would imagine your code looked something like this:

```
lmer(response ~ fixed.effect + (1|Subject) + (1|Item))
```

When you say you can't reproduce your result - is it because an error message? Or you are getting a different result?